# How to pass an object to another page using the useRouter from 'next/navigation'?

Tags: next.js

I am on one page, and I want to redirect the user to another page.
I would like to send an object to the new page using the hook `useRouter` from `next/navigation` because I'm using the app directory. How can I change the code below to pass an object?

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'  
const router = useRouter()
router.push('/dashboard')
```

If I were using the page directory, I would do it like this:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'  
const router = useRouter()
router.push({
  pathname: '/dashboard',
  query: {key : value},
})
```

I didn't find how to do it in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `app` folder, [`router.push(href: string)`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#userouter) accepts as a parameter only the `href` as a string. If you need query strings, you need to set them yourself, as they show in this [example](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params#examples).

In your case, it can be like so:

```js
"use client";

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function ExampleClientComponent() {
  const router = useRouter();

  const createQueryString = (name, value) => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set(name, value);

    return params.toString();
  };

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        router.push("/dashboard" + "?" + createQueryString("key", "value"));
      }}
    >
      Redirect with a query parameter
    </button>
  );
}
```

You would read it with the `searchParams` passed to your page component:

```
// app/dashboard/page.js

export default function Page({ searchParams }) {
  return <div>{searchParams.key}</div>;
}
```

Or using the [useSearchParams](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params) function in any client component:

```
"use client";

import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

export default function Page() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  return <div>{searchParams.get("key")}</div>;
}
```

⚠️: query parameters are stings. You can pass multiple at once. But if you need to pass an object to one key, you need to `params.set("key", JSON.stringify(value))`.
And call `JSON.parse` on the value before using it on the other side.