# How to pass the data to the new page in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a page `/app/mypage/` where I load some data from database. How can I pass this data to the new page in new tab? I.e. I want to have a button which opens `/app/mypage/edit` in such a way that data is passed from `/app/mypage/` instead of loading it again. The object will be relatively large.

Comment: You can find the answer here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76875755/how-to-pass-an-object-to-another-page-using-the-userouter-from-next-navigation

Comment: So I can't pass the entire object but only some query string which could be used to source it again from database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to share same data between different pages.

Using client state management library, using url as state store and etc.

However, If you want to just avoid unnecessary data refetching from the server, I recommend you to use data fetching library(called server-state management library these days) like react-query or SWR. It makes your data cached automatically(distinguised by string like url), so that same data fetching is not happened.